# Part of response ( API )

Tags: python-3.x, api, httpresponse

i have done the below script.

```
def token() :
  url = "https://" +ip_add + ":8443/cas/v1/tickets"
  payload = 'username=' +usr + '&password='+ pwd
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
  response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data = payload, verify=False)
  response.raise_for_status()
  print(response.text)
  if response.status_code == 201:
    print(response.status_code , "OK", " >>> Normal")
  else:
    print("Status : ", response.status_code)
```

and giving me that output :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\"><html><head><title>201 Created</title></head><body><h1>TGT Created</h1><form action="https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-86-wFHhWf7Yt5e1WkYggRcDwvZx9H1x05LlfdFFG6ZfVEwL196oC7-cas01.example.org" method="POST">Service:<input type="text" name="service" value=""><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></body></html>
201 OK  >>> Normal
```

so i need to print or save only part of this output which is :

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-86-wFHhWf7Yt5e1WkYggRcDwvZx9H1x05LlfdFFG6ZfVEwL196oC7-cas01.example.org
```

SOLUTION :
for anyone who is searching for a solution, i have tried the below and it worked with me.

```
tgt = response.headers['location']
  print(tgt)
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont get what you mean but simple regex will do

```
action="(.+)?" method
```

or maybe

```
action=\"(.+)?\" method
```

to escaped double quotes

Comment: my question is i have the below output:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\"><html><head><title>201 Created</title></head><body><h1>TGT Created</h1><form action="https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-86-wFHhWf7Yt5e1WkYggRcDwvZx9H1x05LlfdFFG6ZfVEwL196oC7-cas01.example.org" method="POST">Service:<input typext" name="service" value=""><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></body></html>

and i need to print or store only part of it which is :
""https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-86-wFHhWf7Yt5e1WkYggRcDwvZx9H1x05LlfdFFG6ZfVEwL196oC7-cas01.example.org""

Comment: i see you've already found solution , glad to read that, sorry for misperception